# Не менять размер qtablewidget при изменении размера окна

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть `QTableWidget` с двумя столбцами и 2 `QGroupBox`(объединенные по вертикали сплиттером). Таблица выполняет роль меню и, соответственно, **не должна изменять свой размер при растягивании всего окна**, в то время, как 2 `QGroupBox` **должны его менять**. 
Как добиться такого поведения при изменении размера формы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для `QTableWidget` задайте `Size Policy` - `Horizontal` в значение `Fixed`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или из кода:

```
ui->tableWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, ui->tableWidget->sizePolicy().verticalPolicy());
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один способ - это выставить минимальный и максимальный размер QTableWidget одинаковым, выбрав при этом желаемый размер объекта